# how to print getValidInteger? python

Tags: python, spyder

I'm a beginner in the Python language. I have my getValidInteger function which is:

```
def getValidInteger():
    isValid = False
    
    #initialize strInput
    strInput = ""
    
    while (not isValid):
        #get string input from the user
        strInput = input('Enter an integer: ')
        isValid = IsValidInteger(strInput)
        if (not isValid):
            print('Invalid integer was entered: try again')
            
    #after exiting the loop return strInput cast to an int
    return int(strInput)
```

However, I cannot call that function in the line code below. It shows Typererror: TypeError: getValidInteger() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

```
setSizeSmall = um.getValidInteger('Enter a small size of each subset:')
```

I want the output to look like :

```
Enter a small size of each subset:
```

Comment: First of all, what is `um`? Second, what do you think should happen to `'Enter a small size of each subset:'` and why is that

Comment: um is the other classes that I implemented to use the getValidInteger function.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is your `IsValidInteger()` function but it doesn't seem to take arguments.
Instead, you can use the `isdigit()` method like this

```py
def getValidInteger():
    isValid = False
    
    #initialize strInput
    strInput = ""
    
    while (not isValid):
        #get string input from the user
        strInput = input('Enter an integer: ')
        isValid = strInput.isdigit()
        if (not isValid):
            print('Invalid integer was entered: try again')
            
    #after exiting the loop return strInput cast to an int
    return int(strInput)
```